# What game do I play?

Tags: word, connect-wall, connections-puzzle

> Find the game that I know,
> Using the clues below.
> Subtractive unit, toad hesitation;
> Digital dungeon, show staircase;
> Pop dancing, tropical mint;
> Dog therapy, oil ring.
> Once done, find the sun -
> It has an age, but it's for fun.
> Cryptically, there's more than one.
> Find the hidden message in this riddle.
> It's right here, but not in the middle.
> It's required to freeze this griddle.

*Puzzle made by myself.*

Comment: is it just me, or are the connect wall words all a pattern of stressed, unstressed => stressed => unstressed?